# Error when converting VB.NET App to from 32-bit to 64-bit

Tags: .net, vb.net, enterprise-library

I’m working on converting a VB.net desktop application from 32-bit to 64-bit.

The application consists of 3 layers which are

1. VB.NET Standalone Application
2. Broker Service
3. WCF Service

The VB.NET 'Standalone Application' calls the Broker Service. 'Broker Service' then calls the ‘WCFService’ in order to connect to the database.
All 3 projects are converted into 64 bits and published on the Web server.

After the conversion, it throws the below error in runtime.

The project ran without any issues when it was in the 32-bit mode.

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'NavigatorMD.Core.Broker.CurrentUserSerializable' to type 'NavigatorMD.BusinessLogic.CurrentUserSerializable'.

Source Code

```
Public Shared Function GetUserInfo(ByVal productId As String) As CurrentUserSerializable 
 Dim args(6) As Object 
 SetupArgs(args) 
 args(0) = "getuserinfo" 
 args(4) = args(3) 
 args(5) = productId 
 
Dim retVal As Object = BrokerService.ProcessRequest(args, False) 
  Return CType(retVal, CurrentUserSerializable) 

  Public Function ProcessRequest(ByRef args() As Object, ByVal noConnectionStringNeeded As Boolean) As Object 

        Dim inValue As Broker.ProcessRequestRequest = New Broker.ProcessRequestRequest() 
        inValue.args = args 
        inValue.noConnectionStringNeeded = noConnectionStringNeeded 
        Dim retVal As Broker.ProcessRequestResponse = CType(Me,Broker.IBroker).ProcessRequest(inValue) 
        args = retVal.args 
        Return retVal.ProcessRequestResult 
    End Function
```

**I suspect the error is because the function ‘GetUserInfo()’ doesn’t return the value.**

Please find the full error message below.

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Project.Core.Broker.CurrentUserSerializable' to type 'Project.BusinessLogic.CurrentUserSerializable'.
> at Project.Core.ServiceProxy.GetUserInfo(String productId) in D:\GitHub Source codes\Prj_D180 - Devexpress 18 - Copy\Core\Data Objects\ServiceProxy.vb:line 934
> at Project.Core.CurrentUser.GetUserInfo(ApplicationMap& _applicationMap) in D:\GitHub Source codes\Prj_D180 - Devexpress 18 - Copy\Core\Data Objects\CurrentUser.vb:line 471
> at Project.Core.CurrentUser.AuthenticateUser(String LicenseKey, ApplicationMap& _applicationMap) in D:\GitHub Source codes\Prj_D180 - Devexpress 18 - Copy\Core\Data Objects\CurrentUser.vb:line 261
> at Project.MainForm.IsUserAuthenticated() in D:\GitHub Source codes\Prj_D180 - Devexpress 18 - Copy\Project\MainForm.vb:line 347
> at Project.MainForm..ctor() in D:\GitHub Source codes\Prj_D180 - Devexpress 18 - Copy\Project\MainForm.vb:line 182
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.CreationStrategy.InitializeObject(IBuilderContext context, Object existing, String id, ICreationPolicy policy)
> at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.CreationStrategy.BuildUpNewObject(IBuilderContext context, Type typeToBuild, Object existing, String idToBuild)
> at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.CreationStrategy.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type typeToBuild, Object existing, String idToBuild)
> at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.ReflectionStrategy`1.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type typeToBuild, Object existing, String idToBuild)  at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.ReflectionStrategy`1.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type typeToBuild, Object existing, String idToBuild)
> at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.ReflectionStrategy`1.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type typeToBuild, Object existing, String idToBuild)  at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.SingletonStrategy.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type typeToBuild, Object existing, String idToBuild)  at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.TypeMappingStrategy.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type t, Object existing, String id)  at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderBase`1.DoBuildUp(IReadWriteLocator locator, Type typeToBuild, String idToBuild, Object existing, PolicyList[] transientPolicies)
> at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderBase`1.BuildUp(IReadWriteLocator locator, Type typeToBuild, String idToBuild, Object existing, PolicyList[] transientPolicies)  at Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.Collections.ManagedObjectCollection`1.BuildFirstTimeItem(Type typeToBuild, String idToBuild, Object item)
> at Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.Collections.ManagedObjectCollection`1.Build(Type typeToBuild, String idToBuild, Object item)  at Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.Collections.ManagedObjectCollection`1.AddNewTTypeToBuild
> at Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.CabShellApplication`2.OnRootWorkItemInitialized()  at Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.BuilderStrategies.RootWorkItemInitializationStrategy.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type typeToBuild, Object existing, String idToBuild)  at Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.BuilderStrategies.CommandStrategy.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type t, Object existing, String id)  at Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.BuilderStrategies.EventBrokerStrategy.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type t, Object existing, String id)  at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.MethodExecutionStrategy.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type typeToBuild, Object existing, String idToBuild)  at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.PropertySetterStrategy.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type typeToBuild, Object existing, String idToBuild)  at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.CreationStrategy.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type typeToBuild, Object existing, String idToBuild)  at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.ReflectionStrategy`1.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type typeToBuild, Object existing, String idToBuild)
> at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.ReflectionStrategy`1.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type typeToBuild, Object existing, String idToBuild)  at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.ReflectionStrategy`1.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type typeToBuild, Object existing, String idToBuild)
> at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.SingletonStrategy.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type typeToBuild, Object existing, String idToBuild)
> at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.TypeMappingStrategy.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type t, Object existing, String id)
> at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderBase`1.DoBuildUp(IReadWriteLocator locator, Type typeToBuild, String idToBuild, Object existing, PolicyList[] transientPolicies)  at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderBase`1.BuildUp(IReadWriteLocator locator, Type typeToBuild, String idToBuild, Object existing, PolicyList[] transientPolicies)
> at Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.WorkItem.BuildUp()
> at Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.CabApplication`1.Run()
> at Project.MainProg.Main() in D:\GitHub Source codes\Prj_D180 - Devexpress 18 - Copy\Project\MainProgram.vb:line 14

Comment: What does `Convert` mean? .NET applications are CPU-agnostic. If you target `AnyCPU` they'll just run on whatever is available. Changing that flag doesn't affect the application UNLESS you try to use a native library.

Comment: The error itself has *nothing* to do with bitness. `Unable to cast object of type 'Project.Core.Broker.CurrentUserSerializable' to type 'Project.BusinessLogic.CurrentUserSerializable'`. That's a cast error, caused by using the wrong types. It may be caused by `Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder` an obsolete class that died over 13 years ago. It was part of Enterprise Library which itself died before 2010 as all of its functionality was incorporated into .NET Framework *2.0* or was replaced by better libraries. `ObjectBuilder` is a very early attempt to create a DI and AutoMapper tool

Comment: It's quite possible that `ObjectBuilder` picked the wrong types using reflection, probably because it loaded the wrong assembly. There's no EntLib code in the question so it's impossible to say what's wrong.

Comment: Why don't you use `AnyCPU` instead of trying to target 64-bit? If you have memory issues it's almost certainly due to memory leaks, not the 2GB RAM limit. Why would a service require 2GB RAM? The *real* problem is trying to use a 13-year old library

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for your comments. This is a legacy code and we are trying to do some optimizations. Let me try switching to `AnyCPU` and get back with the results.